How to combine first 3 pages of pdf into a new pdf
I want to extract the first three pages of a pdf, display them for approval, then create a new pdf which has just those approved pages. I am using Ghostscript.net in a c# app that extracts the pages I need into bitmaps and I have the save and approval sections working.  However, I am at a loss for the following:

pageimage.Save does not have "pdf" as an image format in Ghostscript.net - how is this done?
How do I "concatenate" or insert the bitmaps so they come out as individual pages in the resulting pdf.
Is there a different library I need to create the resulting pdf?

Your assistance is appreciated.
My extract code is shown attached
 GhostscriptVersionInfo lastInstalledVersion =
     GhostscriptVersionInfo.GetLastInstalledVersion(
         GhostscriptLicense.GPL | GhostscriptLicense.AFPL,
         GhostscriptLicense.GPL);
// Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo gvi = 
//     new Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Ghostscript.NET.dll");

 byte[] binaryPdfData = null;
 binaryPdfData = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
 var pdfDataStream = new MemoryStream(binaryPdfData);

 using (var rasterizer = new Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer())

 {
     rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-dNEWPDF=false");
     rasterizer.Open(pdfDataStream, lastInstalledVersion, false);

     System.Drawing.Image pageImage1 = rasterizer.GetPage(100, 1);
     System.Drawing.Image pageImage2 = rasterizer.GetPage(100, 2);
     System.Drawing.Image pageImage3 = rasterizer.GetPage(100, 3);

     Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(100, 100);
     // Create a graphics object from the new bitmap
     using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resized))
     {
         // Set the interpolation mode to high quality bicubic
         g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
         // Calculate the scaling ratio
         double ratioX = (double)resized.Width / (double)pageImage1.Width;
         double ratioY = (double)resized.Height / (double)pageImage1.Height;
         double ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
         // Calculate the new width and height based on the scaling ratio
         int newWidth = (int)(pageImage1.Width * ratio);
         int newHeight = (int)(pageImage1.Height * ratio);
         // Calculate the position of the image on the new bitmap
         int posX = (resized.Width - newWidth) / 2;
         int posY = (resized.Height - newHeight) / 2;
         // Draw the original image onto the new bitmap
         g.DrawImage(pageImage1, posX, posY, newWidth, newHeight);
         pageImage1.Save(outfiletn + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     }
     

     rasterizer.Close();

 }


Thanks in advance

The pdfs are huge and I have thousands of them stored locally (5TB) and no money to spend on more server space.  The project to implement is a "library" of Thumbnails with abstracts where the end user will get a "peek" at the short version, then request the full version via an eMail message.  I think iText will do what I want, but I have to learn that tool now.  I was hoping GS could help since I'm a bit more familiar with it.

On a Windows Devices it would be far simpler, for viewing to invoke MSEDGE --app= and let the user close the pop-up after 3 pages.
The equivalent native GhostScript command would be gswin##c.exe -q -dBATCH -dLastPage=3 -sDEVICE=display -r100 annots.pdf and user presses enter key 3 times after each page to exit.
Unless the files are gargantuan, in which case write the 3 pages as %temp%\temp.pdf and delete afterwards if not acceptable. You could do similar with Chrome or Safari on other OS.
msedge.lnk --app="%cd%\annots.pdf"

The whole point of GhostScript is its fidelity and speed of use so why not simply write the PDF anyway, then display for user to, delete or keep !
bin\gswin32c.exe -dLastPage=3 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o%temp%\temp.pdf -f annots.pdf & msedge.lnk --app="%temp%\temp.pdf"

Only add the -q switch after testing.

If you need to do a whole set, you can use a numeric list to write them faster, than the user is likely to read and approve the first 3 pages. Just ensure the temporary "discards" are flushed from %temp% before a second run.
In comments you say you want to use PDF as a low quality sampler of 3 page this can be easily done. the 3 pages above were 169 KB but as low quality image will be 75.6 KB, yet still readable. You can reduce resolution lower if suitable.
gswin32c.exe -dLastPage=3 -sDEVICE=pdfimage24 -r96 -o%temp%\temp.pdf -f annots.pdf & msedge.lnk --app="%temp%\temp.pdf"



With iText 7 or later and .NET on Windows, I only needed to do this
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(destinationPath));

 // Open the source PDF
 iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument insertDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file));

 // Copy the first outputpagect from the source PDF to the destination
 insertDoc.CopyPagesTo(1, outputpagect, pdfDoc, 1);

 // Close the source PDF
 insertDoc.Close();

 // Close the destination document
 pdfDoc.Close();

